# Dividing country into maps of scale 1:25000 (metres)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale, vector-grid, data-driven-pages

I want to divide a country into a grid of maps that will be of 1:25000 scale. I am not sure how to approach this. Create fishnet seems like a good ending point. I have some old maps of the given scale.

Do I just create a template A4 outline and multiply that?

I also need to think about the corners and such, to extend the maps that fall outside of the country and make the extended blank (white). These old maps that I have cover approximately 10km x 14km and are A4.

Should I follow this or?

Basically, I want to subdivide the country into regions of the same size and scale 1:25000.

Comment: What is you next step, create PDFs? Use Data Driven Pages with your fishnet as index layer. Try different fishnet sizes and set scale at 1:25000 until you get enough overlap etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a combination of a [Grid Index](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/grid-index-features.htm) and [Data Driven Pages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm) to divide your country into a grid, and a [Multiple Ring Buffer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm) to provide a white background outside the country's border.

The following assumes that you have a polygon feature describing the country's border. The one I've used here is not a 100% perfect fit, but it will give you an idea of the technique.

1. In the **Grid Index Features** tool, specify the country border feature as your **Input Features**. Choose a **Polygon Width** of about 7000m and a **Height** of about 4800m (these will give you about 1:25000 scale on A4 paper).

[image]

2. This will produce a grid covering the extent of the country's border.

[image]

3. In the Layout view, right-click the page, choose **Page and Print Setup**, and set your paper to A4. In the main toolbar, set your **scale** to 1:25000. Optionally, you can uncheck the grid index layer so it's not visible (I've left it on for clarity).

[image]

4. From the Data Driven Pages toolbar, choose **Set Up Data Driven Pages**. On the **Definition** tab, choose **Enable Data Driven Pages**. Set your **Layer** to be the grid index features you created above.

[image]

5. On the **Extent** tab, choose **Center and Maintain Current Scale**.

[image]

6. To create a white background, choose the **Multiple Ring Buffer** tool. Set your **Input Features** to be the country border. Set the **Distance** to be 20000m (or another distance of your choice, depending on the size of your grid). Choose **Outside Polygons Only** to avoid covering the country feature itself.

[image]

7. This creates a buffer feature to serve as a background. Notice that by choosing a buffer size larger than our grid size, the background will fill the borders of any given output page.

[image]

8. When you are ready to output your file, choose **File/ Export Map...** Choose **Save as type = PDF**. On the **Pages** tab, choose the appropriate page range(s).

[image]